# Compare Start_date to current date in SQL

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I need to compare start_date to current_date so that i could found the data of the particular day(In other words: data of the day). For this, i am using this query

```
    $rs = $this->db->select('ult_camp.*')
                    ->order_by('ult_camp.start_date', 'desc')
                    ->from('ult_camp')
                    ->where('ult_camp.status', 'Active')
                    ->where('date(ult_camp.start_date)<=', date('Y-m-d h:m:s'))
                    ->get()->result();
    return $rs;
```

But this query i'm getting the data whose start_date is less than the current date.Please Help me to get this.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `date('Y-m-d h:m:s')`.... `m` is months, not minutes; use `i` for minutes

Comment: And the MySQL [date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function returns only the `Y-m-d` part of a stored date value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add another where to get the date range for the day starting 12:00:00 until the present time.

```
 $rs = $this->db->select('ult_camp.*')
                ->order_by('ult_camp.start_date', 'desc')
                ->from('ult_camp')
                ->where('ult_camp.status', 'Active')
                ->where('date(ult_camp.start_date)<=', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))
                ->where('date(ult_camp.start_date)>=', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'))
                ->get()->result();
return $rs;
```

This where clause should translate to:

```
date(ult_camp.start_date) <= '2017-09-02 08:55:20' AND date(ult_camp.start_date) >= '2017-09-02 00:00:00'
```

**Note**: i -> is for minutes and m -> is for month in php date formats